# Deploying a static site with root-links on github pages

Tags: github-pages

I'm trying to deploy a static website on github page and as many have faced, github add a "/my-repository" level in the URL breaking all the root-links working properly in local

I think I pretty much understand the problem which is basically this : https://maximorlov.com/deploying-to-github-pages-dont-forget-to-fix-your-links/

As the article describe, it is possible to resolve the issue by using a framework. and setup environnments

I have unsuccesfully tried to use the workflow "GitHub Pages Jekyll" but I think it require to convert the local workspace too

I'm looking for alternatives, I'd like to keep it simple on my project side (just plain old html/css/js)

- Maybe write 404.html page to redirect if needed
- Is it possible to read an envrionnement variable and prefix all links (with  for exemple
- Some solutions in github actions ?